# Python: Matching/Substitution on multiple patterns

Tags: python, regex

I would like to match a function definition in a LISP-like code. The function can be defined in either 4 formats

```
1. procedure(functionName(argList) mainCode)    
2. (procedure functionName (argList) mainCode)    
3. defun(functionName(argList) mainCode)
4. (defun functionName (argList) mainCode)
```

I am using the code as below to match the above possibilities using the **re.search**. This works fine. However when I capture the match using **match.group(1)** then this only works if the match happened on the first pattern.

**Question**: How to capture all 4 possibilities?

```
#!/usr/bin/python -tt

import os
import re # Import regular expression module
import sys

# traverse root directory, and list directories as dirs and files as files

def GetFunctionsFromSkillFile(skillFile):
  with open(skillFile) as f:
    data = f.readlines()
  for line in data:
    # Match Procedure
    match=re.search(r'^\s*procedure\(\s*(\w+)|^\s*\(\s*procedure\s+(\w+)|^\s*defun\(\s*(\w+)|^\s*\(\s*defun\s+(\w+)', line)
    if match:
      # Capture the match
      print('{0}.autoload="{1}"'.format(match.group(1), os.path.basename(skillFile)))

# Python boiler plate call.
if __name__ == "__main__":
  # Quick check on arguments
  if len (sys.argv) < 2:
    print ('Usage:  CreateAutoloadsFile.py skillDirectory')
    sys.exit(2)
  # Get the Excel file from cmd line arguments
  skillDir = sys.argv[1]
  # Traverse
  for root, dirs, files in os.walk(skillDir):
    for file in sorted(files):
      if re.search(r'.il$', file):
        #print(file)
        file = root + "/" + file
        GetFunctionsFromSkillFile(file)
```

Comment: Any guarantee about the depth of nesting of the `()`?

Comment: @nhahtdh This is not important here. The match works fine, not so much the substitution

Comment: Depends on the data, it might or might not be a good idea to proceed with regex. I'll answer your main problem shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite your regex as:

```
r'^\s*(?:[(]\s*(?:defun|procedure)\s+|(?:defun|procedure)\s*[(]\s*)(\w+)'
```

Then regardless of the format, the name can be found in group 1.

Comment: Thank you Sir ! This works but returns unexpected results. In fact, it returns "NONE.autoload" if the match is not on the first pattern.

Comment: @Riad: `None` is returned when there is no match found. Without the data, there is not much I can help. Do note that you are currently anchoring the search to the beginning of the string (and my regex preserve that behavior)

Comment: Yes the anchoring on the beginning is intended. The print statement only happens if there is a match, that's why I'm puzzled as for the presence of the NONE in the outputs. I shall post some data tomorrow morning. Thx a lot @nhahtdh

Comment: This actually worked as expected, now that I have managed to test it in all possible combinations. Thank you so much!